# Redis Sentinel sdown at start up

Tags: centos-7, redis

I'm experiencing a weird issue.

When I try to launch Redis in sentinel mode, such as:

```
redis-sentinel /path/to/sentinel.conf
```

everything was working, but a few seconds later, it puts the state **+sdown master mymaster x.x.x.x 6379**

Here is my configuration file:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 x.x.x.x
port 7878
sentinel myid cfe5dc23d93e439544ca2c076c134309b35c021d
sentinel monitor mymaster x.x.x.X 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 0
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/tmp/redis"
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 0
sentinel current-epoch 0
```

I also looked at `iptraf-ng`, and found the connection "RESET" every time it tries.

Can anyone find reason along with the solution, regarding the eventual factors that'd make this happen?

EDIT: All the ports are open.

Comment: Of course you should tell us what OS you are using ...

Comment: Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: CentOS 7 is the OS used